# ctags not working recursively as required

Tags: ctags

I came across a very confusing problem, the `ctags` command cannot generate TAGS for subdirectories, I'm using ctags to generate TAGS for emacs, I first cd to the root directory of the project, and run command as:
`ctags -e -R *`, TAGS only generated for the current directory, but subdirectories not generated, my ctags version is:

```
$ ctags --version
Exuberant Ctags 5.9~svn20110310, Copyright (C) 1996-2009 Darren Hiebert
  Compiled: Oct  7 2014, 13:52:37
  Addresses: <dhiebert@users.sourceforge.net>, http://ctags.sourceforge.net
  Optional compiled features: +wildcards, +regex
```

I have tested, the `ctags -R *` also cannot generate tags file for subdirectories.

I also tried `find . -name *.py -print | xargs ctags -e -R`, just gives no output, but with `find . -name *.py`, lots of `.py` files are found, can someone help?

by `ctags -VR .` I find it actually goes to the subdirectories and recognizes the python script files, though there is a lot of unknown languages, but it just does not generate the tags file.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you are using Exuberant Ctags http://ctags.sourceforge.net/.
you can check the same using **ctags --version** command.